# How can i add reverse transaction (scale-down / Zoom out effect) on this PopUp box when it disappear or close

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can i add reverse transaction (scale-down / Zoom out effect) on this PopUp box when it close after clicking anywhere outside area. Just like when text is selected the popup comes, same reverse animation i want when it close.

How can i add reverse transaction (scale-down / Zoom out effect) on this PopUp box when it disappear or close

```js
  const container = document.querySelector('.storypara');
  const popupContainer = document.querySelector('.popupContainer');

  // this method is added
  // It gives the text of HTML of selected text :)
  function getHTMLOfSelection () {
      var range;
      if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.htmlText;
      }
      else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
          var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
          return div.innerHTML;
        }
        else {
          return '';
        }
      }
      else {
        return '';
      }
    }


  container.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    const selectedText = getHTMLOfSelection(); // First get the raw HTML text
    if (selectedText) {
      //selectedText.split("<").join("&lt");    // Now replacing the < so that browser don't render it
      //selectedText.split(">").join("&gt");   // Also replacing the > so that browser don't render it
      //console.log(selectedText);
      showPopup(selectedText); // using the 'xmp' tags around the text, to show the html as it is 
    }
  });

  popupContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('.popupContainer')) {
      popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
    }
  });

  function showPopup(selectedText) {

    // set the selected text as html inside popup element
    document.querySelector('.popup').innerHTML = selectedText;
    popupContainer.classList.add('show');

  }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


.popupContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;


}
 
.h2 { background-color:yellow; }

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.popup {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 80%;
}

    /* Transction / Animation Start here */
    
.popup{-webkit-animation:scale-up-center .4s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000) both;animation:scale-up-center .4s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1.000) both}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-center{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5)}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}}@keyframes scale-up-center{0%{-webkit-transform:scale(.5);transform:scale(.5)}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}}
```

```html
<div class="storypara">

<p><strong>A Bold example Line</strong><br>
Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. Here are some examples of paragraphs. </p>


</div>

<div class="popupContainer">
  <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

How can i add reverse transaction (scale-down / Zoom out effect) on this PopUp box when it disappear or close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed example: https://codepen.io/annaazzam/pen/pogdmWN

The code change using `transition` instead of `animation`:

- Hide the opacity of the container, instead of setting `display: none`
- Add a `transition: transform` to `popup`
- Adding the `scale(0.5)` to the `popup`
- Adding `scale(1)` to popup when `show` is applied

Using `animation` just happens when something first appears in the DOM. Instead, try `transition` which lets you smoothly transition between values when a class name is applied/removed.